# std::from_chars doens't compile under MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I have a little function that uses `std::from_chars` to create a date object from a `std::string_view`, while it compiles using clang or gcc under ubuntu it doesn't using msvc under windows.

```
date::year_month_day parseDate(const std::string_view& s)
{
    int y { 0 }, m { 0 }, d { 0 };

    std::from_chars(s.begin(), s.begin() + 4, y);
    std::from_chars(s.begin() + 5, s.begin() + 7, m);
    std::from_chars(s.begin() + 8, s.begin() + 10, d);

    return date::year { y } / m / d;
}
```

For each of `std::from_chars` call the following error is displayed at compile time:

> 'std::from_chars': none of the 14 overloads could convert all the argument types

The compiler then proceeds to make a list of possible overloads and i clearly see the one that I'm trying to use:

> 'std::from_chars_result std::from_chars(const char *const ,const char *const ,int &,const int) noexcept'

The last parameter has a default value. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [`std::string_view::begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/begin) doesn't return a `const char *`.

Comment: You want to use [`std::string_view::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/data) instead which returns a `const char*` as required by [`std::from_chars()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by **Some programmer dude** and **Ruks**, `std::string_view.begin()` doesn't return a `const char *const`, `std::string_view.data()` was the method i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is correct - `from_chars` doesn't play nicely with `string_view`.

However, for others finding the same issue in future, there is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2007r0.html) to add the relevant overloads to `from_chars`.

Progress on this can be tracked [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/744).