# Why does theMicrosoft Visual C++ library implementation 'unwrap' iterators?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

Throughout [microsofts stl implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/STL), pretty much all of their iterators are *unwrapped* before they are used.

For instance, [for_each](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/algorithm) looks like this:

```
template <class _InIt, class _Fn>
_Fn for_each(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _Fn _Func) { // perform function for each element [_First, _Last)
    _Adl_verify_range(_First, _Last);
    auto _UFirst      = _Get_unwrapped(_First);
    const auto _ULast = _Get_unwrapped(_Last);
    for (; _UFirst != _ULast; ++_UFirst) {
        _Func(*_UFirst);
    }
    return _Func; }
```

_Adl_verify_range checks that `first <= last`, which I understand, but I dont quite understand the purpose of _Get_unwrapped():

```
#if _HAS_IF_CONSTEXPR
template <class _Iter>
_NODISCARD constexpr decltype(auto) _Get_unwrapped(_Iter&& _It) {
    // unwrap an iterator previously subjected to _Adl_verify_range or otherwise validated
    if constexpr (is_pointer_v<decay_t<_Iter>>) { // special-case pointers and arrays
        return _It + 0;
    } else if constexpr (_Unwrappable_v<_Iter>) {
        return static_cast<_Iter&&>(_It)._Unwrapped();
    } else {
        return static_cast<_Iter&&>(_It);
    }
}
#else // ^^^ _HAS_IF_CONSTEXPR / !_HAS_IF_CONSTEXPR vvv
template <class _Iter, enable_if_t<_Unwrappable_v<_Iter>, int> = 0>
_NODISCARD constexpr decltype(auto) _Get_unwrapped(_Iter&& _It) {
    // unwrap an iterator previously subjected to _Adl_verify_range or otherwise validated
    return static_cast<_Iter&&>(_It)._Unwrapped();
}
```

It seems that it wants to decay the iterator, or cast it to an rvalue reference.

So my question is why does Visual++ use this paradigm? GCC does not do this as far as I can tell.

**EDIT**

As requested, source of [iterator._Unwrapped()](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/iterator)

```
_NODISCARD constexpr _Ptr _Unwrapped() const noexcept {
    return _Myptr;
}
```

_Myptr is defined in the iterator itself, and is just a raw pointer:

```
template <class _Ptr>
class unchecked_array_iterator {
...
private:
    _Ptr _Myptr; // underlying pointer
}
```

Comment: What is `_Unwrapped()`? I guess MS iterators have some debugging-related wrappers.

Comment: *does this not introduce overhead* -- I see `constexpr`, so what overhead are you referring to?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the latter version is not constexpr, if its not available. Even with constexpr it would have more compilation time. Perhaps I should have been more careful with my wording. I have updated the question, im mainly just interested in why it does this.

Comment: @IgorR. I discarded this because its a bit of a rabbit hole, and I dont have enough expierence to make it clear. But yes, this is built into the iterators, and it seems to simply call _Unfancy(), which returns the appropiate pointer.

Comment: @rustyx I have included it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why does VC++ wrap iterators?**

It's a design choice. Indeed, for array-like types like `std::array` and `std::vector` an iterator can be a simple `typedef` to `T*`, which satisfies iterator semantics nicely, and indeed this is how GNU stdlibc++ implements it. But from the standard perspective, `iterator` is a *pointer-like* object, but isn't necessarily a pointer. So...

1. Assuming that it's a pointer would be a mistake and could lead to non-portable code ([case in point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61203317/stdfrom-chars-doenst-compile-under-msvc)).
2. Wrapping iterators allows for iterator debugging (see [`_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/iterator-debug-level?view=vs-2019)). For example here's a debug `operator++`:

   ```
   _CONSTEXPR17 _Array_const_iterator& operator++() {
       _STL_VERIFY(_Ptr, "cannot increment value-initialized array iterator");
       _STL_VERIFY(_Idx < _Size, "cannot increment array iterator past end");
       ++_Idx;
       return *this;
   }
   ```

**Why does VC++ unwrap iterators?**

1. It's an optimization of error reporting. In loops like `std::for_each`, instead of getting a range error in the middle of `for_each`, the error is signaled upon entry into `for_each`.
2. It's a performance optimization.

   - In Debug mode, checking the preconditions once leads to faster code (debug mode is 10+ times slower already, so performance still matters even in debug mode).
   - In Release mode the compiler can optimize pointer access better than inferring it via an iterator every time. Yes, it can still infer it in most cases, but an additional level of indirection can lead to different decision-making with regard to inlining elsewhere in the code.

Comment: If this is the case, it seems odd that they bothered making these iterator wrappers in the first place. GCC simply uses T* as an iterator for an stl array, whereas Visual++ has a custom array iterator class. So apparently they build this iterator wrapper, and then subsequently unwrap it in every function it is to be used. Seems odd - unless ofcourse im missing all the cases where it indeed is usefull.

Comment: In Debug builds iterator does range checking. And it would be bad if an iterator was a typedef'd pointer, that could lead to non-portable code. Hence the unwrapping is an implementation detail that is meant to be hidden from the user.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is a debugging feature.

The wrapped iterators contain additional information that allows the implementation to verify various preconditions, such as whether two iterators form a valid range, that an iterator has not been invalidated, that an iterator is used only with a container to whose element it refers.
`_Adl_verify_range` is one such check.

But then, when the iterator is actually used in the algorithm, the implementation does not want to incur the overhead of the verifications (which would happen for each `++` operation). It unwraps the iterator to a version that does not have the safety features. Usually this means, that the unwrapped version is just a pointer (not necessarily a naked one, but wrapped in a class).

In Release builds, the algorithm itself can be optimized well because only very simple types are involved and no checks, but the initial safety checks can remain or can be omitted, as the developer wishes.